# How do I return variables from serverside back to the clientside script?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I found this article by the plugin author: https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/ but the problem is that it redirects to a URL that is known beforehand. I need to know the URL as a response from the server, because the redirect URL will depend on the submitted values.

I can log the event:

```
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}, false);
```

But I am not at all sure how much of the data is provided by the server and how much by the client script. I tried altering the submission like this:

```
add_action('wpcf7_posted_data', 'alter_input');

function alter_input($data) {
    $data['your-message'] = 'Something totally different here.';
}
```

But my alteration seems to have no effect on what data the event object contains. I have trouble finding where exactly the response (if any) is formulated and what filters or actions apply.

**EDIT:** I reworded the question; too many answers and comments get stuck into the *why*, which is irrelevant, or try to suggest "other approaches", which isn't what I asked, instead of just sticking to the *how*.

Comment: it will depend on submitted values so why you need server response ?

Comment: AJAX submission? Just use `location = 'someURL.php'` after response.

Comment: @PHPglue it's a plugin so we don't have full control over JS code

Comment: @TemaniAfif The redirect url has parameters that need to be calculated by the server. The submitted values are the basis for the calculation.

Comment: you may do this calculation inside the JS in the listerner, no ? i know it may be unsafe, but ot will depend on the kind if treatement

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not sure it is possible in this particular case. The URL in question is a precalculated payment URL for a money transaction. The payment information is sent to the payment gateway for validation using their API and then the gateway returns the URL. I think that's too sensitive an operation to perform clientside.

Comment: so you mean you are using something else with Contact Form 7 ? another plugin ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not another plugin, but another service (if I understood correctly what you meant with your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to find what I was looking for. The AJAX request to the server returns actually only three variables, eg:

```
{
    into:"#wpcf7-f19-p59-o1",
    message:"An error occurred. Please try again later.",
    status:"mail_failed"
}
```

So no luck there. There is no hook or filter to modify the response serverside, to add more variables. And even if there was a way, the clientside javascript is not coded in such a way that it would be easy to overwrite singular methods to achieve the functionality that I want. It would require an ugly copy pasta of hundreds of lines to change just a couple little things.

Thus my verdict is that this is not doable, at least not for now, unless the plugin author decides to make some changes that could accommodate this kind of functionality, wink wink. I'll just implement a form processing action myself. That'll be less work.

Answer (score 2):

you may try this :

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;

    for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( 'name-of-the-field' == inputs[i].name ) {
            //make your test on inputs[i].value and rediret
        }
    }
}, false );
```

Answer (score 1):

They say

> The simplest way is utilizing Contact Form 7’s custom DOM event to run 
>   JavaScript. The following is an example of script that redirects you to another 
>   URL when the wpcf7mailsent event occurs:

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
     location = 'http://example.com/';
 }, false );
</script>
```

but they don't offer any access to the server response.

The only solution would require you to add in the server response under the `onSentOk` a javascript string (a serialized object) which will be evaluated line by line.

They say in **scripts.js**:

```
 if ( data.onSentOk ) {
    $.each( data.onSentOk, function( i, n ) { eval( n ) } );
 }
```

so in **rest-api.php** instead of:

```
if ( ! empty( $result['scripts_on_sent_ok'] ) ) {
    $response['onSentOk'] = $result['scripts_on_sent_ok'];
}
```

you have to add your url logic, something like:

```
$response['onSentOk'] = array('top.location.href="' . $cutomUrl .'";');
```

But again, this plugin wasn't designed to do anything with the server response ;)

**Update**

Another solution, since you may not have access to plugin files, is to make a second ajax request, this time to one script that is yours:

```
 document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'your_scrit.php',
         data: sameData,
         success: function(response){
            // do your redirect
         }
      });
 }, false);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the problem. There's not the necessary data available and no way to make it available.

Comment: @SimonJosefKok  just showed you how to make it available :)

Comment: You did? Didn't you just say: "but they don't offer any access to the server response."? Maybe I'm just too tired now :D

Comment: Problem is not lack of access to plugin files but rather that modifying 3rd party plugin files is a bad practice. I'm not doing it. Sending a second request kinda defeats the purpose of using the plugin in the first place, because it requires it's own serverside validation mechanic and the whole shebang. But hey, I appreciate the help anyway. :)

Comment: If you operate payments and use plugins like that one, you already have bigger problems than modifying 3rd party files :)) However, my update with a second ajax call should solve your problem without changing any 3rd party files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and none of the answers above were helpful. Actually this is feasible, you may follow the below code (add it to functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_ajax_json_echo', 'filter_wpcf7_ajax_json_echo', 10, 2 );
    
function filter_wpcf7_ajax_json_echo( $items, $result ) { 
    
    $items['foo'] = 'bar';
        
    return $items;
        
};
```

You will then be able to access the new element with the below javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {

    console.log( event.detail.apiResponse.foo );

}, false );
```

By the way, you may want to use the event `wpcf7mailsent` over `wpcf7submit` as suggested in some answers as `wpcf7mailsent` will fire only if the form is successfully submitted (eg. all required fields are filled properly) which is not the case of `wpcf7submit`.

Comment: At last nice to see someone has directed people to the right way. But there is a slight change with the filter hook name. It is `wpcf7_feedback_response`. The function signature is the same though.